# iMacros FF: How to de-select text after EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS ctrl+a?

Tags: firefox-addon, imacros

I am trying to de-select previosly selected text (select nothing) after having selected and copied it with Keypress events:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="a" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="c" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
```

I have already tried using the *CLICK* and *DBLCLICK* events on random elements of the page, also using alternative mouse buttons (1,2) e.g.:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD>TABLE:nth-of-type(4)>TBODY>TR>TD:nth-of-type(3)>TABLE>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(4)>TD>TABLE:nth-of-type(2)>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(5)>TD>TABLE>TBODY>TR>TD:nth-of-type(2)" BUTTON=0
```

and also using XPATH instead:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK XPATH="/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/strong" BUTTON=0
```

In both cases the targeted elements are marked but nothing else happens.
The target is a simple html document structured by tables containing mostly text.

I also tried to use CLICK with point coordinates:
   CLICK X=784 Y=166

And, as suggested in other questions, to use a short delay before the event:
   WAIT SECONDS=1

Please note, that the first event *(EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="a" MODIFIERS="ctrl")* works flawlessly.

Edit: The version of iMacros for Firefox I was using, was 9.03, the accepted solution works only up to 8.97.

Comment: That's odd. Something like `EVENT TYPE=CLICK POINT="(0,0)"` actually works if it's executed as its own script, but when it occurs after a `EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="a" MODIFIERS="ctrl"` in the same runtime it fails. Not sure if bug or feature :?

Comment: Try to record a click on the HTML controls that can be changed manually, i.e. input, select, textarea, checkbox.

Comment: @Shugar Unfortunately there are no such elements on the page I run the script on.

Comment: @PinkiePie Indeed it works in a separate script.

Comment: You could ask about this in the official forums http://forum.imacros.net/viewforum.php?f=11 Maybe someone there knows what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no input elements on the webpage, let's append one:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="a" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS CHAR="c" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
WAIT SECONDS=1

URL GOTO=javascript:(function(){var<SP>t=document.createElement("input");t.setAttribute("id","tempInput");document.body.appendChild(t);})();
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#tempInput" BUTTON=0
URL GOTO=javascript:(function(){var<SP>t=document.querySelector("#tempInput");document.body.removeChild(t);})();
```

Obviously, this solution is far from ideal but it does its work (except 'iMacros for Firefox' v.9.0.3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can not test it as I always get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined, line: 2` in Chromium. Perhaps there is a problem with my setup (lubuntu 16.04 32bit with Chromium 59.0.3071.109). A very crude solution for Firefox (which I am using) is to just reload the page with `REFRESH`.

Comment: If you use 'iMacros for Firefox' v.9.0.3, try to downgrade it to v.8.9.7. (The best version ever.) This code must work for you as well.

Comment: Your solution worked with v.8.9.7. I will edit my question to include the iMacro version I was using.